# How to set a particular keybinding in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using vim extension for vscode.

How do i enable keybinding that allows me to press **ctrl+j or ctrl+k to go down or up the options** while i'm in the **quick open** menu?

Also how do i enable **ctrl+j and ctrl+k to go down or up the options** when i'm viewing the **command history of terminal**? Currently pressing ctrl+k gives the result: "ctrl+k was pressed. Waiting for second key of the chord..."

Comment: `Ctlr+K` is used in a few default keybindings as a prefix key, you have to remove all of them in your `keybindings.json`, see the doc file on key binding, then define a new key binding for your use cases, simpler is to use a different key combo that is not used yet

Comment: I dont know which property of the keybinding to modify to set that ctrl J and ctrl K functionality. @rioV8

Comment: you first have to remove all keybindings with prefix `Ctrl+K`, read the doc page

Comment: Turns out in all cases except while pressing ctrl + p or while pressing ctrl + r to view history in terminal, ctrl+k and ctrl+j have already been overwritten to focus to top widow split and focus to bottom window split respectively.

This was done by the vim extension for vscode and settings defined in .vimrc.

I want to overwrite the functionality of ctrl k and ctrl j on those 2 aforementioned conditions as well, but i dont know which command's keybinding to modify to achieve that result.

Comment: pretty important to leave out the mentioning of the vim extension, it rewrites all keybindings

Comment: I edited it now. But what do i do to set the keybind tho? I just want to know for which command in vscode i need to set the key binding?